# Meteor - writing image content to the browser from server

Tags: meteor

I have a server method that makes the API call to get the contents of an image file.

```
getImageApi: function (param1, param2, imageType) {
            var url = http:/somehost/image?param1=' + param1 + '&param2=' + param2 + '&imageType=' + imageType;
            var response = Meteor.http.call('GET', url, {
                headers: {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"},
                responseType: "buffer"
            });

            if (response.statusCode == 200) {
                return new Uint8Array(pdfResponse.content);
            }
            else {
                throw new Meteor.Error(pdfResponse.statusCode);
                return "";
            }
            return "";
        }
```

The parameter imageType can have values such as jped, tiff, raw, png etc..

The server side route is calling this method and writing the content to the window.

```
Router.route('/image', function () {
    var param = queryParam;

    var param1 = param.param1;
    var imageType = param.imageType;
    var param2 = param.param2;

    var content="";
    Meteor.call('getImageApi', param1, param2, imageType, function (error, result) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("Error occurred on receiving data");
                content = "";
            } else
                content = new Buffer(result);
        });
    }
    this.response.writeHeader('200', {
        'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    });
    this.response.write(content);
    this.response.end();
    }
}, {where: 'server'});
```

If I specify the content-type as "image/jpeg" in the response, it shows a broken image on the window. If I do not specify any content-type it downloads a .tiff file no matter what type of image the api returns.

I wanted to know what am I missing. Is it the something while returning the data from server method (conversion to buffer and Uint8Array)? or something on the server route (content-header and other header parameters) ?

Comment: You need to use the synchronous version of `Meteor.call` (no callback) otherwise the content won't be defined when you send the response. I don't know if that's the only problem but that's a good place to start.